# Как скопировать колонку DataFrame в переменную без нулей?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть объект `DataFrame` заполненный значениями `numpy.int64`. Нужно скопировать одну из его колонок с названием `ETRN` в переменную, но исключить из копии все нулевые значения.

Пример кода:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"ETRN":pd.Series([0, 2.2, 3.4, 0, 12.3], index=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']), 
"num": pd.Series([10, 12, 7, 2.1, 22], index=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

copy = df['ETRN'] #так получается полная копия колонки, а нужно без нулей

print(df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [9]: copy = df.loc[df["ETRN"] != 0, "ETRN"].to_numpy()

In [10]: copy
Out[10]: array([ 2.2,  3.4, 12.3])
```

если в итоге нужно получить Pandas Series:

```
In [11]: copy = df.loc[df["ETRN"] != 0, "ETRN"]

In [12]: copy
Out[12]:
2     2.2
3     3.4
5    12.3
Name: ETRN, dtype: float64
```